# Flutter enable mutliselection of tabs of Gridview

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to enable multiselection functionality for my `GridView`, but I when I click on any tile all the tiles get automatically selected, I want to enable the tile selected and deselected on tile click. Please help to select and deselect multiple tabs.

Here is code:

```
void toggleSelection() {
  setState(() {
    if (_isSelected) {
      // mycolor=Colors.white;
      _textColor = Colors.deepOrange[400];
      _borderColor = Colors.deepOrange[300].withOpacity(0.8);
      _isSelected = false;
    } else {
      //  mycolor=Colors.grey[300];
      _textColor = Colors.black;
      _borderColor = Colors.white;
      _isSelected = true;
    }
  });
}


List<Widget> _getTiles() {

  final List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < listResponseData.length; i++) {

    bool isSelected = _serviceindex == i;
    tiles.add(Container(
      //decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6), color: Colors.grey),

      child: ListTile(


        selected: _isSelected,

        title: new GestureDetector(
          child: new Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                border: Border.all(color: _borderColor),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: new Text(listResponseData[i].nativeText,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: _textColor),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {

            toggleSelection();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
  return tiles;


}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the code where `_serviceindex` is being used? Looks like that's what keeps track of what's selected, but it doesn't seem to be updated anywhere and it also doesn't seem to be a list, which would be needed for multiple selections.

Comment: i've just declared it as `int _serviceindex = 0;`

Comment: All of your ListTile share the _isSelected variable so they will all be either selected or deselected depending on the value of _isSelected.  As you have a list of items you also need to have a list of bool flags(instead of just one bool value) for each item, so each row will have its own selection flag so it can be toggled independently from the other rows.

Comment: can you please give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue, here is the working code.

```
  List<ResultResponse> newListResponse = new List();

class ResultResponse {
int id;
String name;
String nativeText;
String image;
bool isSelected;

ResultResponse(this.id, this.name, this.nativeText,
  this.image, this.isSelected);
}

 List<Widget> _getTiles() {

  final List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < newListResponse.length; i++) {

    //_isSelected = _serviceindex == i;
    tiles.add(Container(
      //decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6), color: Colors.grey),

      child: ListTile(

        title: new GestureDetector(
          child: new Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                border: Border.all(color: newListResponse[i].isSelected ?
                Colors.deepOrange[300].withOpacity(0.8) : Colors.white),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: new Text(newListResponse[i].nativeText,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                    color: newListResponse[i].isSelected
                        ? Colors.deepOrange[400] : Colors.black  ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {

            toggleSelection( i);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
  return tiles;
}



void toggleSelection( int i) {
  for(int j=0;j<newListResponse.length; j++)
    print(newListResponse[j].isSelected);

  setState(() {
    if (newListResponse[i].isSelected) {
      listSelectedServices.remove(i);



      newListResponse[i].isSelected = false;
    } else {

      listSelectedServices.add(i);

      newListResponse[i].isSelected = true;
    }
  });
}
```